# Telerik RadGrid Scroll Paging issue

Tags: telerik, radgrid

I am working with Telerik RadGrid and I am having an issue on scroll paging.

I have a page size of 10. My grid is displaying about 5-6 rows and other rows are overflown at the bottom.

Now, when I start scrolling, it jumps to page 2 instead of showing other rows in the grid. It should post back for paging when other page records are visible and it should scroll up.